# Doing regression with Caffe using EuclideanLoss layer

Tags: regression, caffe, loss-function

I'm using the Caffenet model. I did a classification task with 9 classes successfully. Then I tried to change it to a regression network by preparing another LMDB file with labels ranging from 700 to 1400. I changed the original training code and replaced the softmax with EuclideanLoss and num_outputs to 1. I did the same for testing and got this error:

"Check failed: ExactNumBottomBlobs() == bottom.size() (2 vs. 1) EuclideanLoss Layer takes 2 bottom blob(s) as input. * Check failure stack trace: * Aborted (core dumped)"
So I commented out EuclideanLoss layer:

layer { name: "prob" type: "EuclideanLoss" bottom: "fc8-cats-dogs-n" top: "prob" }

but now I get:

File "testr.py", line 86, in pred_probas = out['prob'] KeyError: 'prob'

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: `The Euclidean loss layer computes the sum of squares of differences of its two inputs`

Comment: Share the last part of your `prototxt` file.